# Debugging XSLT with Intellij and Saxon - Unsupported Transformer

Tags: xslt, intellij-idea, saxon

I'm currently trying to convert xml files to a completely different format, using IntelliJ Community Edition +Saxon to write and debug the stylesheet.
I have already Saxon-HE 9.7.0-5 as the top-most module dependency.
Running the stylesheets with the XSLT-Runner works just fine, but when I try to debug it, I get some errors.

When I specify no VM arguments I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Transformer: net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl
at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.engine.local.LocalDebugger.prepareTransformer(LocalDebugger.java:98)
at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.engine.local.LocalDebugger.<init>(LocalDebugger.java:51)
at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.engine.remote.DebuggerServer$1.<init>(DebuggerServer.java:55)
at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.engine.remote.DebuggerServer.<init>(DebuggerServer.java:55)
at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.engine.remote.DebuggerServer.create(DebuggerServer.java:71)
at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.XSLTDebuggerMain.start(XSLTDebuggerMain.java:53)
at org.intellij.plugins.xslt.run.rt.XSLTRunner.main(XSLTRunner.java:143)
```

When I specify the VM-Arguments

-Dxslt.transformer.type=saxon

as recommended [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1818?pr=), I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The URI http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions does not identify an external Java class
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I've no experience of trying to debug XSLT stylesheets with the IntelliJ plugin, but it seems from these messages that the XSLT processor in use is Saxon 6.5.5. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651209/xpath-functions-does-not-identify-an-external-java-class

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that was what happening. What confused me was that the comments on the plugin page I [linked](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1818?pr=) to state that XSLT 2.0 is supported.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA Supports Saxon 9 Debugging up to Saxon 9.3.0.11.

As of Saxon 9.4.0.0 the `net.sf.saxon.lib.TraceListener` interface introduced braking changes `net.sf.saxon.lib.TraceListener#open()` => `net.sf.saxon.lib.TraceListener#open(Controller)` that got never adapted by JetBrains.

Since Maven artifacts for 9.3 are hard to come by you might want to manually get it from from SF.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.3/

Regarding your stack trace; It has a different story but ultimately results in going back to 9.3.

As of today, 9.3 seems to be the latest version that works with the current IntelliJ 2017.1.2 version.